# Failing to obfuscate Java code with ProGuard

Tags: java, optimization, jar, proguard, executable-jar

I'm trying to optimize / obfuscate a java project with ProGuard.
I extract the project as a runnable jar from eclipse, and it runs just fine.

When I try to compress it with ProGuard, I get thousands of warning and errors, in particular at the end:

```
Note: there were 1 classes trying to access generic signatures using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the signature attributes
      (using '-keepattributes Signature').

Note: there were 14 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Note: there were 2 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
      You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
      their implementations (using '-keep').

Note: there were 15 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').

Warning: there were 13229 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
Warning: there were 61 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
         You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
         be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
Warning: there were 18 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
```

The external libs I used in the project are added to the jar upon exporting it from eclipse. ("Extract required libraries into jar"). I did not use the "repack into jar" option because it really slows jars down.

The libs in particular are:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

Am I doing something fondamentally wrong here?

I have tried without success the suggestions of proguard, and my code compiles in eclipse with no warnings.

It's a very big project so I can't really provide an MCVE, but if someone could point me in the right direction here as to what I'm missing, I'd really appreciate it.

Example of the warning: (It goes on for every single method)

http://pastebin.com/m9hX9LJA

Obviously this might be too general of a problem for you guys to fix, however I might be doing some major obvious mistake that I'm not realizing, that's what I'm going for with this.

Answer (score 0):

Notes are just suggestions, but warnings point out inconsistencies in the input. Notably, the 13229 unresolved references suggest that you are providing the main code of your application (with -injars), but not its libraries (with -injars or -libraryjars). I don't know of Eclipse's Extract or Repack options, but you should check the contents of your input jar(s).

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass).